# javascript setTimeout - in chrome console doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout, jconsole

I want to click on all the objects on the web page.
Using script in google chrome console.
But I want to wait a moment after each click.

The following script works, but everything happens immediately without delay.
How to write the script to make the delay work?

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _56bs _56bt');
 for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
   setTimeout(  inputs[i].click() , 6000);
}
174
ErrorUtils caught an error: "Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and no...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl5j3.jpg)

Comment: There is so much wrong there that it doesn't even begin to cover answer in as one question. For starters, dont invoke a function, reference pass it, secondly don't make all the timeouts run at once if you expect to wait after each click, thirdly, do not use an iterator because it will be increased before your trigger fires the last time. Please format the question properly and try to localize the issue that you have to one of these

Comment: @Vadim Aidlin I think your first answer `setTimeout( inputs[i].click() , i*1000)` is wrong as **Dellirium** pointed it out. Firstly, you might intend  `setTimeout(()=>{inputs[i].click()} , i*1000)`. Secondly, you should not use iterator or index number in this pattern becuase `i` equals `inputs.length`  in every `inputs[i].click()`.

Comment: ok.  I have following script - this scrupt works well in google chrome console.
But I need a small pause every click   to make the web think I'm human and not a robot.
How can I do it ?



<code>
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _56bs _56bt');
 for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
  inputs[i].click();
}
</code>